# Firebase Cloud Functions post to Telegram API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that needs to do a `post` to the Telegram API that sends a message to an user via a Telegram bot. When I send a message to the bot, I can see it hits my Cloud Function with the correct data, but when I do the `post` in my Cloud Function to the Telegram API, I get the following error:

`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.telegram.org api.telegram.org:443`

I've tried to many code sets to post it all here and I've also tried the [Telegram Bot API](https://github.com/arcturial/telegrambot) as well.

Here's my latest code (typescript) attempt I've tried:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as https from 'https';

export const telosbots = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    let message = request.body.message;
    console.log(`REQUEST INFO`, message);

    let options: https.RequestOptions = {

        host: 'https://api.telegram.org',
        path: '/bot<bot_token_comes_here>/sendMessage',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    let req = https.request(options, resp => {

        resp.setEncoding('utf8');
        resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', e => {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
    });

    let body = JSON.stringify({ chat_id: message.chat.id, text: `Test` });
    req.write(body);
    req.end(`ok`);
});
```

Comment: have you tried `curl` https://curl.haxx.se/ to test the API is working as expected?

Comment: @RonRoyston I used Postman to test my Cloud Function (I commented out the `post` to Telegram request) and the Telegram API. Both endpoints worked perfeclty via Postman